# Highliging genes common with colnames

Tags: r, loops, intersection

I have an empty matrix in which genes are in columns and samples in rows like

```
> head(empty_matrix[,1:4])
      TP53 CDKN2A KRAS MYC
t_005   NA     NA   NA  NA
o_005   NA     NA   NA  NA
t_013   NA     NA   NA  NA
o_013   NA     NA   NA  NA
o_021   NA     NA   NA  NA
o_036   NA     NA   NA  NA
>
```

For each sample I have a list of genes; For instance for sample t_005 I have these genes I want to highlight which ones exist in the colnames of my empty matrix

```
LRRK2
NAV3
PCDH17
AXIN1
ZFHX3
TP53
SMAD4
CCDC102B
STK11
SCN3A
CHL1
CTNNB1
EPHA3
SLIT2
FBXW7
ARID1B
EGFR
ABCB1
CDK6
BRAF
KCNQ3
```

If a gene exists in colnames of my matrix I want to write ***MUT;*** for that; For instance for sample ***t_005*** if I have ***gene TP53*** I want to write ***MUT;*** in column correspond to gene TP53 and sample ***t_005*** because ***TP53*** exists in colnames of my matrix I don't know how to do that

Comment: *I have a list of genes*: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) See also sections 2.7 and 5.2 of [R-intro.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) that comes with your installation of R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.biostars.org/p/305509/  In this post I found the answer